# Determining whether a value exists in an array

Tags: bash

Thank you very much for helping!!!

I have the following code:

```
base[0]='coordfinder'
base[1]='editor_and_options'
base[2]='global'
base[3]='gyro'
base[4]='movecamera'
base[5]='orientation'
base[6]='sa'

for d in $dest_include/*; do
    if [ $d == "${base[@]}" ]; then
        echo $plugin='y' >> vt_conf.sh
    else
        plugin=$(basename $d)
        echo $plugin'?'
        read $plugin
        echo $plugin=${!plugin} >> vt_conf.sh
    fi
done
```

It doesn't work, but it's a good starting point.
Basically the thing that doesn't work is the if loop. I just made it up because I don't know how to do it.

I'd like to do the following:

Loop through the content of $dest_include folder.
If any of the forlders ($d) matches any of the elements in the array do one thing, else do something else.

Thanks!!!

Comment: It returns '-bash: [: too many arguments coordfinder?' It actually shouldn't ask for coordfinder as it's in the array, but I'm not surprised as it also returns a too many arguments error

Comment: @RafaelGP When that's passed to the `[` command (yes, it's a command, not native shell syntax), the array is already expanded, so the shell gets this: `[` `coordfinder` `==` `coordfinder` `editor_and_options` `global` `gyro` `movecamera` `orientation` `sa` `]`; that's the "why" behind your error. (By the way, using `==` with `[ ]` isn't valid POSIX syntax -- it's a bash extension causing your shell to accept `==`, as opposed to `=`, as valid at all).

Comment: Thank for your comment about the == I've fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through an inner loop, setting a flag if you find a match.

```
base=( coordfinder editor_and_options global gyro movecamera orientation sa )
for d in "$dest_include/"*; do
  found_match=0
  for i in "${base[@]}"; do
    [[ $d = "$i" ]] && { found_match=1; break; }
  done
  if (( found_match )) ; then
    ...do one thing...
  else
    ...do the other...
  fi
done
```

Comment: What a pro! I love your answer! In order to make it work I had to change the 5th line to: [[ $(basename $d) = "$i" ]] && { found_match=1; break; } Adding basename the code works beautifully!

Comment: @RafaelGP You can do one better than basename: `[[ ${d##*/} = "$i" ]]` is a parameter expansion that does the same thing, but with no subshell (so faster).

Answer (score 0):

you could also turn the check around: use the whole array as a whitespace-separated string, and try to match a whitespace-delimited word within it.

```
for d in "$dest_include"/* do
    if [[ " ${base[*]} " == *" $(basename "$d") "* ]]; then
        do something with matching directory
    else
        do another thiing
    fi
done
```